# Why does GDB say "no line number info available" when symbolizing a crash dump using dSYM file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gdb, crash-dumps, debug-symbols

I built a Mac OS X application which is configured to strip the debug info for Release and create the dSYM files.

(Project is configured as described here: http://bit.ly/tJEQml a cached version of http:/developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html which does exist anymore)

As expected the generated crash reports for my app don't show line information for the stack trace of my apps internal calls.

When analyzing a crash report I just can't get **GDB** or **atos** to give me line information for the stack-trace.

Crash report excerpt:

```
0   CoreFoundation          0x00007fff920f7286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib         0x00007fff91f74d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation          0x00007fff920f70ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   CoreFoundation          0x00007fff920f7044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
4   CoreFoundation          0x00007fff920b429b -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 219
5   AppName                 0x00000001015e9c61 AppName + 85089
```

I tried on **GDB** by doing the following:

1. called `gdb -arch x86_64`
2. loaded the app using the `file` command (tried both the AppName.app and Content/MacOS/AppName)
3. GDB prompts that the symbols where loaded (even tried loading the dSYM with `file`)
4. called `info line * 0x00000001015e9c61`
5. GDB responds with `No line number information available for address 0x1015e9c61`

I tried with **atos** by doing the following:

1. called `atos -arch x86_64 -o AppName.app` (also tried to the binary directly and to the dSYM's DWARF file)
2. typed `0x00000001015e9c61` and hit enter
3. atos simply repeats `0x00000001015e9c61`

What could be wrong?

The symbols seem to load properly (at leasts that's what gdb reports) and I'm certain the crash, dSYM and App bundle all match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still haven't figured out how to make the manual symbolizing work but I found a nice script which will do it automatically.

The script can be found at: https://github.com/nikyoudale/symbolicatecrash-mac

I will read through the script's code to figure out what it's doing and answer my own question.

Comment: This has been so useful, I still don't know what I was doing wrong but I just couldn't get logs to symbolicate, but this script worked fine. Now on to actually solving my bug now that I've found it...